# Disable std::map::at()

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, dictionary

I'm compiling some code with gcc4.7, which was written for c++11, but I'd like it to be compatible with gcc4.4. The weird thing is that code with `std::map::at()` (which is only supposed to be defined in c++11) used doesn't seem to give me compiling errors, even after I remove the `-std=c++11` flag. I'd like to be getting compiler errors, since this code has to be shared with colleagues who may not be using gcc4.7. Is this normal? Is there some way to restrict the behavior of `std::map`?

Comment: Did you try `-std=c++03 -pedantic` ?

Comment: did now... it prints a lot of warnings from the headers I'm including, but nothing about the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to achieve this with a new *gcc* and new libraries, at least without compiling them yourself.

**As a practical solution**, assuming you have a relatively modern PC (6+GB of memory, perhaps 4GB will do), I suggest you

1. Install an older Linux distro in a virtual machine, which has both the desired old *gcc*, and matching old standard libraries. This is far less hassle, than trying to set up an alternative compiler and library environment in your main development OS.
2. Keep your sources in version control, if you already don't.
3. Either set up a script in the old VM to check out and build the software manually, or go the extra mile, and set up a [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on the VM, and create a job to poll your version control repo and do a test build automatically when you do commit on your main development environment.

Good thing about this is, you can easily set up as many different environments and OSes as you want to keep compatibility with, and still keep the main development OS up to date with latest versions.

---

**Original answer** for the ideal world where things work right:

To get strict C++03, use these flags:

```
-std=c++03 -pedantic
```

Also, if you only want to support *gcc*, you may want `-std=g++03` "standard" instead, but unless there is some specific feature, say C99-style VLA, which you really want to use, then I'd recommend against that. You never know what compiler you or someone else may want to use in the future.

As a side note, also recommended (at least if you want to fix the warnings too): `-Wall -Wextra`

---

**Sad reality** looks like selecting the C++ standard indeed does not solve the problem. As far as I can tell, this is not really a problem in the *gcc* compiler, it is a problem in the GNU C++ standard library, which evidently does not check the desired C++ standard version (with `#ifdef`s in header files). If it bothers you, you might consider filing [a bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) (if there already isn't one, though I did not find one with [a quick search](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)).

Comment: with this the compiler gives me a lot of warnings for the headers I'm using, but nothing about `std::map::at()`.

Comment: I suggested an edit to put the "solution" earlier in the answer... accept it if you like...

Comment: @Shep Unofortunately the edit suggestion seemed like it was already rejected in review, but good idea, I edited myself and put the practical solution first.